# I am trying to create React App but I am getting this output?

Tags: reactjs

$ npx create-react-app my-app
npx: installed 98 in 53.457s

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Projects\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-09-05T07_43_27_276Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Projects
Done.

Comment: Have you read the log to see what the error was? There is usually more detail in the log file than was output to the console.

Comment: Check ending lines from logs...Maximum call stack size exceeded....


2401 verbose cwd C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Projects\my-app
2402 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
2403 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "--save-exact" "--loglevel" "error" "react" "react-dom" "react-scripts" "cra-template"
2404 verbose node v12.18.3
2405 verbose npm  v6.14.6
2406 error Maximum call stack size exceeded
2407 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Answer (score 1):

Clean npm cache:

`npm cache clean --force`

then try again

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect and reconnect to your source of internet (WIFI).
or restart your pc.
{This is usually caused when your WiFi connection is unsatble}
After that, run npm cache verify
Next you will want to run:npx create